# Measure Theory definition of Random Variable

Tags: measure-theory

The following is the definition of a random variable:

> Let $(\Omega, \mathbb{F}, P)$ be a probability space. A random variable is a real-valued function X on $\Omega$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}, \{\omega:X(\omega) \in B\} \in \mathbb{F}, ∀B∈B(\mathbb{R})$

I don't understand how this makes sense if our choice of $F$ can be arbitrary.

Let's say we are rolling a biased dice such that each side has a different probability, and the information we know about the system is $F = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2, ..., 6\}, \Omega\}$ -- then for this $F$, according to the definition, $X$ is not a random variable (because you could construct a (disjoint) Borel set which covers the probabilities of e.g. $\{1, 3, 5\}$, and $\{1, 3, 5\}$ is not in $F$). How does this make sense?

Comment: Generally measurability depends on both algebra(sigma algebra), in domain and in image. What you mean under "choice of F can be arbitrary" ? What you choose measurable sets from this and the measurability will depend.

Comment: Your definition does not make sense.  It should be either "For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\{\omega : X(\omega)\leq x\} \in F$" or "For all Borel measurable sets $B \subseteq\mathbb{R}$ we have $\{\omega : X(\omega) \in B\} \in F$."  You can show these are both equivalent.

Comment: While technically correct, you probably missed that when $\Omega$ is denumerable (finite or countably infinite) then probabilists _always take (without exceptions)_ the sigma field $\mathscr{F} = 2^\Omega$ (the power set of $\Omega$). Then, _all functions_ $X:\Omega \to \mathbf{R}$ are random variables. In fact, we probabilists want this to be true for every $\Omega$ but it is known that you cannot extend a measure over all subsets of an uncountable $\Omega$ unless the measure itself is rather trivial...

Comment: ...Therefore, we take for sigma field the next most canonical choice. In $\mathbf{R}^d$ that choice is precisely the sigma algebra generated by the intervals. Properties of sigma fields then show that this is the same as the sigma field generated by the open sets, or the rays $(-\infty, a]$, etc. In general, on a metric space, there are two canonical choices of sigma algebras: the "ball sigma algebra" generated by the open balls of the metric space, and the Borel sigma algebra generated by the open sets. Unless the space is second-countable, the two sigma algebras are different in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well sure, then the biased dice roll would not be a random variable in the sense you're used to thinking about it. However, it is quite meaningless to claim that it should be a traditional random variable in the first place, since $\Bbb F$, or often: $\mathcal{F}$ or $\Sigma$, is (intuitively) the sigma-algebra of possible measurable *events* which we can consider.

With your choice of $\Bbb F$, only the events: nothing, $1$, $\{2\cdots6\}$ or everything, can be considered in terms of probability. It is meaningless to say that the probability of $3$ is different to that of $5$, since neither $3$ nor $5$ are measurable events and as such do not have any sense of probability. You can only ask questions such as: what is the probability $X\ge 2$, or the probability $X=1$. You cannot talk of the probability $X\ge3$ even, since $\{3,4,5,6\}$ is not a measurable event and as such has no probability defined for it.

So: yes, the sigma-algebra of events is arbitrary, but so is the probability space itself. You keep the theory general, and make specific definitions and examples when it suits.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Interpret $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ as performing a random experiment where you pick $\omega \in \Omega$. The sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$ represents the information you know after performing the experiment. So given $\omega \in \Omega$, you know for each $A \in \mathcal{F}$ whether $\omega \in A$. For your example, this means you only know whether $\omega = 1$ or not. The measurable random variables are the functions of $\omega$ that you can know with the information in $\mathcal{F}$.

For a quantitative demonstration of this claim, it can be shown that any nonnegative $\mathcal{F}$-measurable random variable $X$ can be written as $X = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_n 1_{A_n}$ with $a_n \geq 0$ and $A_n \in \mathcal{F}$. Hence $X$ depends on at most countably many events in $\mathcal{F}$. Conversely, if $f \colon \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $B(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}})$-$B(\mathbb{R})$ measurable and $A_1, A_2, \dots \in \mathcal{F}$, then $f(1_{A_1}, 1_{A_2}, \dots)$ is a measurable random variable. So the measurable random variables consist precisely of all the measurable functions of countably many events in $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: Mason! I am intrigued by your claim. It is reminiscent of the fact that, for a $\sigma$-finite atomic space with measure $\mu$, we have the representation $\mu=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\delta_{x_n}$ where the $\delta_n$ are Dirac measures and $\{x_n\}$ a countable set of points. Is there a link? I am sure that this is not true for all measure spaces, so there must be something special about probability spaces